# weird issue with Dell network card

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I have laptop Dell Latitude E5420 with Win 7 professional service back 1 
suddenly the NIC (Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller) and the wireless card (Intel (R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N6205) stop working (I can't connect to the internet both LAN and WiFi)

Windows diagnostic wizard says its the driver I downloaded the driver of both cards from their manufacturers but NO LUCK the problem still exists...last thing I tried is donwloading the Ethernet driver (which is older version than the current one) from Dell website but the installation process takes long time and abort

I don't what is the problem and what shall I do to solver it

help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried removing the device from the Device Manager & letting Windows find it again? [Right click My Computer/Properties then Device Manager. If it's suspect, it will possibly already be marked with a warning triangle]

Comment: I tried no benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after discovering the issue is with the OS itself missing some important files which leads to failure in the OS, whatever driver I install does not work I also could install the IP v4 protocol..therefore repairing the OS solves the issue so later card drive updates enables the connection.

Thanks for the help folks